# ASP MVC Datetime range data annotation from now to 20 years?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, range

I want to put validation on a datetime property with data annotations for something like this

```
    [Required]
    [Range(typeof(DateTime), DateTime.Now.ToString(), DateTime.Now.AddYears(20).ToString())]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate{ get; set; }
```

but it shows this error

```
Error   11  An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type
```

i also have the foolproof validation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have run into this same issue in the past. I have solved it using my own attribute that extends the RangeAttribute class.

```
public class CustomDateRangeAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
    public CustomDateRangeAttribute() : base(typeof(DateTime), DateTime.Now.ToString(), DateTime.Now.AddYears(20).ToString()) 
    { } 
}
```

This would be used like this:

```
[Required]
[CustomDateRange]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate{ get; set; }
```

Comment: can we make this dynamic ?? For example , [CustomDateRange(startDate=DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now.AddDays(5))]

Comment: With some workaround, yes. For example:
`public CustomDateRangeAttribute(int startYear, int endYear) : base(typeof(DateTime), DateTime.Now.AddYears(startYear).ToString(), DateTime.Now.AddYears(endYear).ToString())` which could then be used as `[CustomDateRange(0, 20)]`