# How to do Date validation in Razor .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, razor-pages

Need standard validations for Start and End Dates. Should include:

1. End Date > Start Date.
2. End Date < Today Date.
3. Start Date < End Date

So far tried below approaches, but these do not work completely:
[ASP MVC Datetime range data annotation from now to 20 years?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23529567/)

Please advise.

Comment: What didn't work `"but these do not work completely"`? What you are trying to achieve? Could you please add the code snippet where you are having issue in addition please include your expectations.

Comment: Add code as formatted text, not as image, not as link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fluent validation` to achieve this. I write a simple demo here and hope it can help you.

**Demo**

```
 public class Time
    {
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End  { get; set; }
    }
```

**DateTimeValidator**

```
public class DateTimeValidator : AbstractValidator<Time>
    {
      
        public DateTimeValidator()
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            RuleFor(x => x.Start)
                .LessThan(x => x.End)
                .WithMessage("Start must < End")
                .NotEmpty(); 

            RuleFor(x => x.End)
                .GreaterThan(x => x.Start)
                .WithMessage("End must > Start")
                .NotEmpty();
        }
    }
```

**Page**

```
@model Time

<form asp-action="Time" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Start" class="control-label" ></label>
                <input asp-for="Start" class="form-control" type="date" max='' id="startDate"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Start" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="End" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="End" class="form-control" type="date" max='' id="endDate"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="End" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

@section  Scripts{
    <script>
        //I use js to allow users to select only the latest date up to yesterday
        function addZero(n) {
            return parseInt(n) >= 10 ? n.toString() : '0' + n;
        }
        let dateNow = new Date(),
            yearNow = dateNow.getFullYear(),
            monthNow = dateNow.getMonth() + 1,
            dayNow = dateNow.getDate() - 1,
            maxDate = yearNow + '-' + addZero(monthNow) + '-' + addZero(dayNow);
        let inp = document.querySelector('#startDate');
        let inp2 = document.querySelector('#endDate');
        inp.setAttribute('max', maxDate);
        inp2.setAttribute('max',maxDate);

    </script>
}
```

**Demo**

[image]

**Edit**

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Time(Time modeo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // add your code here.....
                
                
            }
            //return model and error message
           return View(modeo);
        }
```